# Return file in Spring MVC REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, spring-mvc

I have the REST Service Code  Below code which returns a File ,now the problem is in the response body on the PostMan Client I get a raw response ,how can I can convert it so that it displays the contents of the file to the client ,Goal is to return a file to the user .File Name is "File1.jpeg"

Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = URIConstansts.GET_FILE, produces = { "application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getFile(@RequestParam(value="fileName", required=false) String fileName,HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{

    ResponseEntity respEntity = null;

    byte[] reportBytes = null;
    File result=new File("/home/arpit/Documents/PCAP/dummyPath/"+fileName);

    if(result.exists()){
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/arpit/Documents/PCAP/dummyPath/"+fileName); 


        byte[]out=org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

        respEntity = new ResponseEntity(out, responseHeaders,HttpStatus.OK);


    }else{

        respEntity = new ResponseEntity ("File Not Found", HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    return respEntity;

}
```

Comment: you might find the answer here helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68492486/3946706

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The code below solved my problem:

```
@RequestMapping(value = URIConstansts.GET_FILE, produces = { "application/json" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity getFile(@RequestParam(value="fileName", required=false) String fileName,HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException{

    ResponseEntity respEntity = null;

    byte[] reportBytes = null;
    File result=new File("/home/arpit/Documents/PCAP/dummyPath/"+fileName);

    if(result.exists()){
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/arpit/Documents/PCAP/dummyPath/"+fileName);
        String type=result.toURL().openConnection().guessContentTypeFromName(fileName);

        byte[]out=org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.add("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        responseHeaders.add("Content-Type",type);

        respEntity = new ResponseEntity(out, responseHeaders,HttpStatus.OK);
    }else{
        respEntity = new ResponseEntity ("File Not Found", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return respEntity;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! By the way @ResponseBody annotation is not necessary

Comment: Note that spring has response header constants `org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION` and `org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE` that may be used instead of string literals.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream)` **loads the whole file into memory** so it isn't the best solution if you try to load a bigger file.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use different content type instead of produces = {  application/json" }

Content-types

http://silk.nih.gov/public/zzyzzap.@www.silk.types.html

If it still dont work then try to get HttpServletResponse and write your file data to Stream with 
response.setContentType();

Note :: Recently I have use response.getOutputStream to write a Excel file. Due to some reasons setting produces wasnt working for me.

Also you can use Firebug in firefox to see Response headers.

Comment: IT worked when I added  responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);

but how will I dynamically set my media type as it can be txt,image,xml,js,mov any file

Comment: If you know file extensions, you can create a Pre-defiend Map for Extension-CotentType and use it set content type 

responseHeaders.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPES.get(extension));