# Java - How to read xls format data via HTTP request not file

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-poi, inputstream, outputstream

Currently, i need to provide an API for another java application that send xls format response, while when i test in local use MockMVC to get response from my API and use HSSFWorkBook to parse it, while it failed, anyone can help me to show how implement this API in Java?
Very thanks!!!

framework: SpringMVC

my code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/report", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity getReport() {
        LOGGER.info("begin to get report");
//        Workbook dailyReport = reportService.getDailyReport();
        Workbook dailyReport = new HSSFWorkbook();
        OutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            dailyReport.write(outByteStream);
            LOGGER.info("end to get report");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("IOException when write excel to stream, e: {}", e);
        }
        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new HttpHeaders();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        headers.put(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, list);
        return new ResponseEntity(outByteStream, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

test method:

```
@Test
public void testGetMigrationDailyReport() {
    String url = "/report";
    try {
        MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(url)).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
        String response = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        byte[] bytes = response.getBytes();
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

full stacktrace:

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:65)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:167)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:155)
    at com.cisco.csit.wbxmig.web.IntegrationControllerTest.testGetMigrationDailyReport(IntegrationControllerTest.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: I think you supposed to return `outByteStream.toByteArray()`

Comment: See the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641231/return-file-in-spring-mvc-rest .. Looks like it's what you need.

Comment: @secretsuperstar yep, i updated, API could send stream, while the test method could parse stream to WorkBook, will check Garreth's suggestion later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried the below:

It works well. The difference is I am doing `ByteArrayOutputStream.getBytes()`.

```
@GetMapping("/down")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> down() throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
        for(int sNo=1;sNo<=5;sNo++) {
            Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("s"+sNo);
            for(int i=1;i<6;i++) {
                Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
                for(int j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                    Cell cell = row.createCell(j);
                    cell.setCellValue("test "+j);
                }

            }
        }
        wb.write(outByteStream);
        wb.close();

       MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new HttpHeaders();
       List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
       list.add("application/vnd.ms-excel");
       headers.put(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, list);
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(outByteStream.toByteArray(),headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Adding `test`.

The trick is create file from response and then read it again
**create file from response**

```
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/Users/me/Desktop/output.xlsx");
 fos.write(bytes);
 fos.close();
```

**read file**

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/Users/me/Desktop/output.xlsx");
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
```

**Whole test class**

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;



import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers;
import org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;

import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.techdisqus.App;
import com.techdisqus.config.SpringSecurityConfig;
import com.techdisqus.controller.DefaultController;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
/*@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration*/
@WebMvcTest(DefaultController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes= {App.class,SpringSecurityConfig.class
        })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MvcTest {


      @Autowired
        private  MockMvc mockMvc;

      @Autowired
        private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

      @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext wac;

      @Before
        public void setup() {
            this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
                .addFilters(this.springSecurityFilterChain).apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity()).build();
        }


    @Test
    public void testDown() {
        String url = "/down";
        try {

            MvcResult mvcResult = this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(url)).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).andReturn();
            byte[] bytes = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsByteArray();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/Users/me/Desktop/output.xlsx");
            fos.write(bytes);
            fos.close();

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/Users/me/Desktop/output.xlsx");
            Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            int count = wb.getNumberOfSheets();  
            System.out.println("count "+count);
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
              System.out.println(wb.getSheetAt(i).getSheetName());
              //perform asserts here if needed
            }
            System.out.println("done!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @secret super star, what about the test method, the test was failed cause `NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0xC2A0C3118FC390C3, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document` when i use POI read it.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879515/notole2fileexception-invalid-header-signature-read-0x0000000000000000-expecte

Comment: what about use workbook as your stream content, just like that: 
`ByteArrayOutputStream outByteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Workbook dailyReport = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet ddd = dailyReport.createSheet("ddd");
        ddd.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("dddd");
        dailyReport.write(outByteStream);`

Comment: You supposed to read as `mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsByteArray();`

Comment: Why do you want to create sheet ? are you doing in `Api` or test?

Comment: thanks a lot! it works, one more question, as i have get bytes array from response, why i couldn't get use below way to read it into stream?

`
byte[] bytes = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsByteArray();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
`

Comment: I could not follow you. do you mean why you could not use  Workbook `wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);`

Comment: right,  
`byte[] bytes = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsByteArray(); InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);  wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);`
doesn't know why it couldn't.

Comment: this worked for me too. `bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
         Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(bis);`. Not sure if there any jar version differences causing issue.

Comment: Hi secret, it works also, maybe before some bad code haven't been changed, thanks a lot!

Comment: probably yes. i found same earlier because i was just sending some text. may be the cause. but once I create file using poi API and stream it started working.